# With a jquery modular dialog how do I stop the form values from persisting?

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, persistence, jquery-ui-dialog

(Citing source at: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form)

As an example, this works great but each time the form is subsequently opened the user entered values remain. How can I stop this behavior? (the form will be used multiple times on the same page.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        body { font-size: 62.5%; }
        label, input { display:block; }
        input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
        fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
        h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
        div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
        div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
        div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
        .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
        .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
        $("#dialog").dialog("destroy");

        var name = $("#name"),
            email = $("#email"),
            password = $("#password"),
            allFields = $([]).add(name).add(email).add(password),
            tips = $(".validateTips");

        function updateTips(t) {
            tips
                .text(t)
                .addClass('ui-state-highlight');
            setTimeout(function() {
                tips.removeClass('ui-state-highlight', 1500);
            }, 500);
        }

        function checkLength(o,n,min,max) {

            if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
                o.addClass('ui-state-error');
                updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between "+min+" and "+max+".");
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        }

        function checkRegexp(o,regexp,n) {

            if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
                o.addClass('ui-state-error');
                updateTips(n);
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        }

        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                'Create an account': function() {
                    var bValid = true;
                    allFields.removeClass('ui-state-error');

                    bValid = bValid && checkLength(name,"username",3,16);
                    bValid = bValid && checkLength(email,"email",6,80);
                    bValid = bValid && checkLength(password,"password",5,16);

                    bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(name,/^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i,"Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter.");
                    // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
                    bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(email,/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i,"eg. ui@jquery.com");
                    bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(password,/^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/,"Password field only allow : a-z 0-9");

                    if (bValid) {
                        $('#users tbody').append('<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + name.val() + '</td>' + 
                            '<td>' + email.val() + '</td>' + 
                            '<td>' + password.val() + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>'); 
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            close: function() {
                allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
            }
        });



        $('#create-user')
            .button()
            .click(function() {
                $('#dialog-form').dialog('open');
            });

    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

    <form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">

        <h1>Existing Users:</h1>


    <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
        <thead>
            <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John Doe</td>
                <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
                <td>johndoe1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>

</div><!-- End demo -->

<div class="demo-description">

<p>Use a modal dialog to require that the user enter data during a multi-step process.  Embed form markup in the content area, set the <code>modal</code> option to true, and specify primary and secondary user actions with the <code>buttons</code> option.</p>

</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

Comment: You want to reset the form on each open?

Comment: Hmm.. what browser are you using? I just tried your code in FF3.6 and IE7 and both worked fine. Each time I clicked `create new user` button, the modal form was shown empty. That was with jQuery UI 1.8 / jQuery 1.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).dialog('destroy');
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-destroy

Comment: I tried that (at the time they click close or cancel) Doesn't seem to be working. Could I be calling it at the wrong time?

Comment: @stormist - This method doesn't do what you need, destroy is for the widget, it moves the content within the dialog back to it's original location.

Comment: So then I'm safe just getting the element by id and setting value to ""?